# How to change the description of custom AWS IAM policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have a custom policy in AWS IAM.  I would like to change its description, not its name.  How can I do that?

I've tried editing the policy, but that only changes how it works (e.g., assigning privileges).  I don't see how to change the description.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From [`CreatePolicy` documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_CreatePolicy.html):

> **Description:** A friendly description of the policy.
>
> The policy description is immutable. After a value is assigned, it cannot be changed.

Therefore, you'll need to delete it and recreate it to modify the Description.

Comment: The correct answer. Although it does beg the question: why? Policy's can be edited, it makes sense to have an up-to-date description when updating the policy...

Comment: Fish is correct.  I don't want description fields to need to use a level of indirection!  ("To see the description of this policy, click link.to.internal.IP/descrip/policy-12345.txt")